# Skype Button with HTTPS website

Tags: https, skype

If I display my website with HTTP everything is fine. But when I browse with HTTPS, Skype button is not rendered.

Chrome shows this error on console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE 
https://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js
```

And my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
                <div id="SkypeButton_Call_gamirasu.cave.hotel_1" style="float: right; width:85px !important; height:23px !important; margin-top:-65px;">
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     Skype.ui({
                         "name": " ",
                         "element": "SkypeButton_Call_gamirasu.cave.hotel_1",
                         "participants": ["gamirasu.cave.hotel"],
                         "imageSize": 24
                     });
  </script>
```

I couldn't find anything about using Skype with SSL on their document. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23769617/3412775, which contains an answer that works in some cases where the accepted answer here doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use this specific secured (HTTPS) domain for Skype widgets:

```
https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried visiting the URL you provided ? When I try using Chrome, I get to an SSL warning, which is the explanation why you can't load this ressource.

[image]

Comment: Yes I saw that before.